# iterating previous next in a loop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is there a nice idiomatic way to iterate an array in Coffeescript but accessing both the current and the next item inside the loop? For example in Python you can do:

```
[f(current, next) for current, next in zip(a, a[1:])]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for value, index in array
 current = value
 next = if array[index+1] then array[index+1] else null
 alert "#{current} at #{index} #{next}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with this:

```
(f(a[i], a[i-1]) for i in [1..segment.length-1])
```

I couldn't come up with anything better.